# CMUsphinx add words to existing dictionary

Tags: dictionary, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I've created and tested the C hello world application for pocketSphinx and it works very well. I've then downloaded a french model language, and all was also great except that brands that are not French (as Spotify) where not recognized by the decoder.

It was normal, they where not in the `french.dic` file, so I've added an entry in the `french.dic` file:

```
spotify ss pp oo tt ii ff aa yy
```

But nothing changed, pocketSphinx don't recognize Spotify.

I've also created a little custom dictionary and a little grammar with only 3 words, but "Spotify" is never recognized contrary to the 2 others.

Do have I to do something else to make pocketSphinx recognize new words ?

EDIT:

The little grammar I made:

```
#JSGF V1.0;
/**
 * JSGF test grammar
 */

grammar test;

<launch> = lance | ouvre;
<application> = spotify;
public <command> = <launch> <application>;
```

and the little dictionary:

```
lance ll aa nn ss ee
lance(2) ll aa nn ss ee
ouvre ou vv rr
ouvre(2) ou vv rr ee
spotify ss pp oo tt ii ff aa yy
```

Link to the voice recording: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j3qj13vps5bw0ni/AAAR2ELJLDAadMptMPmLZ4jna?dl=0

Comment: In order to get help on this issue you might share the grammar with 3 words you created and the recording where you say "spotify". It might be that spotify is pronounced with "ff ai", not "ff aa yy".

Comment: I can share the grammar but I have not voice recording of me saying spotify. Do I need one ? I mean, I thought that the french model I downloaded was sufficient.
And for the pronunciation, I based myself on other french words, I'm pretty sure about it. but I'll a spotify(2) with your pronunciation to be sure.

Comment: Voice file is required for debugging because I do not know how you pronounce spotify exactly, I need to hear it.

Comment: I added the grammar and the dictionary if it may help. The voice recording will come as soon as i find a way to post it.

Comment: You can upload file to dropbox and give here a link

Comment: I know I take some time but I've added a Dropbox link.

Comment: Works for me, spotify is recognized. "aa yy" seems to be the right variant. What pocketsphinx version do you use?

Comment: I use pocketsphinx-5prealpha. Have you just added "spotify" to your French dictionary or have you done something else ?

Comment: If I run pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm ./fr -lm french3g62K.lm.bin -dict frenchWords62K.dic -infile spotify.raw   with the word "spotify" added in frenchWords62K.dic, the result is "fausses live" and not "spotify".

Comment: You need to add the word both to the dictionary and to the language model (grammar is also a language model). You only added the word to the dictionary, so the result are expected as well.

Comment: Thank you verry much, it works! The issue was that I used a grammar + a binary model. I removed the binary model and everything works now.

Comment: I'm currently trying to add some words to the dictionary, too. I've added my technical words the dictionary file, but I'm afraid I don't know how to edit the grammar part. Would you mind providing more detail on how you fixed this, specifically with pocketsphinx (not Sphinx 4)?